Selection of hashing function on the specified range
I faced a difficult problem of selecting some hash function $ y=Hash(x) $, where x can be any product of a known range of numbers, and y must be bounded on the segment $ [1, N] $, where N is some number that is a square, i.e. the root of this number is also an integer, which is known in advance.
For example, there is a set of any random numbers $ 12, 52, 11, 33, 10 $. $ N = 3 $. Is it possible to find such a function y that any values obtained by multiplication of numbers on the given range will give the result on the segment $ [1,...9] $.
I have been thinking for a long time about modulo transformations. But unfortunately the result does not always correspond to expectations.

What is your specific requirement other than $SHA256(x) \bmod N$?

If I understand correctly, your function cannot reproduce numbers from $ N+1 $ to $ N^2 $ or at least to $ N^2-1 $
